# Equivalent of Function.prototype.apply for an ES6 generator

Tags: javascript, generator, v8, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to build a chainable JavaScript API. (I’m running this in a recent version of V8 with iterators and generators enabled.) In the example below, `setState` is chainable. It also allows you to call it without having to explicitly create a new `Builder` instance. The `chain()` helper function handles that and automatically returns that instance so `setState` doesn't have to worry about it. (First-class functions for the win!)

In addition to the chainable methods I want some "terminating" methods. The kicker is that these "terminators" are generators. The generators yield internal state of a `Builder` instance. The problem is that I can’t figure out an equivalent to `f.apply(that, arguments)` for a generator. I want to be able to call a generator and set its `this` context at runtime, just like you're able to do with `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call`.

The work-around, commented with `Yuck!`, is to expose both the delegated *and* the original generator on the `Builder.prototype`, calling the original from the delegated. Is there any way to implement the equivalent wrapping like the `chain` method without having to expose the `_generate` method on the `Builder.prototype`?

```
function Builder() { this.initialState = 'initialState'; };
Builder.prototype.setState = chain(function(k, v) { this[k] = v; });
Builder.prototype.generate = delegate(generate, '_generate'); // Yuck!
Builder.prototype._generate = generate;


function chain(f) {
  return function() {
    var that = (this instanceof Builder) ? this : new Builder();
    f.apply(that, arguments); // Pass through arguments
    return that;
  }
}

function delegate(gen, _gen) {
  return function*() {
    var that = (this instanceof Builder) ? this : new Builder();
    that.setState('delegated', true);               
    yield *that[_gen](); // Yuck!
  }
}

function *generate(opts) {
  var i = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    yield [Object.keys(this), opts, i].join(',');
  }
}

// Set up a namespace
var ns = {};
ns.setState = Builder.prototype.setState;
ns.generate = Builder.prototype.generate;


var itr = ns
//  .setState('a', 'A')
//  .setState('b', 'B')
//  .setState('c', 'C')
  .generate('options');


var out = [];
for(var value of itr) { out.push(value); }
out;
```

Which returns

```
[
  "initialState,delegated,,0",
  "initialState,delegated,,1",
  "initialState,delegated,,2",
  "initialState,delegated,,3",
  "initialState,delegated,,4",
  "initialState,delegated,,5",
  "initialState,delegated,,6",
  "initialState,delegated,,7",
  "initialState,delegated,,8",
  "initialState,delegated,,9"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key was `yield *gen.apply(that, arguments)` in the anonymous generator wrapper.

```
function Builder() { this.initialState = 'initialState'; };
Builder.prototype.setState = chain(function(k, v) { this[k] = v; });
Builder.prototype.generate = delegate(generate); 

// Reuses or creates a Builder instance and makes it `this` for calling `f`.
// Returns the Builder instance.
function chain(f) {
  return function() {
    var that = (this instanceof Builder) ? this : new Builder();
    f.apply(that, arguments); // Pass through arguments
    return that;
  }
}

// Similar to `chain()` to create a Builder instance if it doesn't exist.
// Generators are terminal, though, so this returns the FunctionGenerator.
function delegate(gen) {
  return function*() {
    var that = (this instanceof Builder) ? this : new Builder();
    that.setState('delegated', true);               
    yield *gen.apply(that, arguments);
  }
}

function *generate(opts) {
  var i = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    yield [Object.keys(this), opts, i].join(',');
  }
}

// Set up a namespace
var ns = {};
ns.setState = Builder.prototype.setState;
ns.generate = Builder.prototype.generate;


var itr = ns
//  .setState('a', 'A')
//  .setState('b', 'B')
//  .setState('c', 'C')
  .generate('options');


var out = [];
for(var value of itr) { out.push(value); }
out;
```

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that I can’t figure out an equivalent to f.apply(that, arguments) for a generator.

Judging from the [ES6 draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html), you don't need an equivalent - you can just use the expression as is. Generator functions (that construct generator instances) are functions, and they inherit (via `Generator.prototype`) from `Function.prototype`; you can use `.call` and `.apply` on them as on any other function.

So the following should work:

```
function delegate(gen) {
  return function() {
    var that = (this instanceof Builder) ? this : new Builder();
    that.setState('delegated', true);               
    return gen.apply(that, arguments); // Pass through arguments
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct, for example:

     (function* () {}) instanceof Function; // true
     var gen = function* () {
       yield this.random(); 
     }
     gen.apply(Math, gen).next().value;
    
I must be doing something else wrong in my code. Let me take another stab.

Comment: Notice that my `delegate` function does no longer return a generator `function*` - it returns a normal `function` (that returns a generator).

Comment: Right. I adjusted my solution below to return a generator that yields the result of the applied generator.

Comment: Unncessarily complicated :-) Also, it does no more work with normal functions as arguments `gen` to `delegate`…

Comment: Yes, your solution does work too, but I'm not sure why. Yours returns a function where the consumer is expecting a generator. Maybe the fact that gen.apply returns an iterator provides the same effect as yielding the result, as in my implementation. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, a `function` is pretty much indistinguishable from a genarator `function*` as long as both return an iterable generator when being called.